# What are Oracle hidden fields?

Tags: oracle, hidden-field

[ALL_TAB_COLS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1179.htm) differs from [ALL_TAB_COLUMNS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1180.htm#I1020277) in that hidden columns are not filtered out.

What are hidden fields?

> This view differs from "ALL_TAB_COLUMNS" in that hidden columns are
>   not filtered out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hidden columns are columns that exist in the table but that cannot be selected.  There are various reasons that Oracle might create a hidden column-- two of the more common reasons are

- When a column is marked as unused but not dropped, it is hidden
- Oracle [virtual columns](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=510) create hidden columns in the table

Various other Oracle features may create hidden columns as well though those features tend to be more esoteric (i.e. if memory serves, interMedia creates a couple of hidden columns to track various bits of data).

Comment: "Oracle virtual columns create hidden columns in the table"
that's not quite right.

Virtual columns are not hidden (they will show up in select * from table).

Oracle added explicit "invisible"/hidden columns only in 12c.

Comment: Hidden columns are also used to support temporal validity - where you can have enhanced date/time queries of data as it existed at a point in time.  See http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/ilm/temporal/temporal.html

Answer (score 4):

Oracle uses them internally (see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96594/adobjadv.htm) AND you can define such columns for your own tables... when accessed without proper authorization they display NULL instead of the real value (see http://www.techrepublic.com/article/hide-sensitive-data-with-oracle-10g-column-masking)...