# How do I identify all of the invisible columns in an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle

I created a table with an invisible column:

```
CREATE C39293.JUNK (
  id          NUMBER,
  JUNKCOL VARCHAR2(50) INVISIBLE
);
```

Verified that the table was created :

```
select * from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'JUNK'
```

Output:

```
1   THE_OWNER_SCHEMA    JUNK    JUNKCOL VARCHAR2            50          Y           (WideMemo)                                  CHAR_CS 50  NO  NO      50  B   NO  YES NONE    NO  NO          
2   THE_OWNER_SCHEMA    JUNK    ID  NUMBER          22          Y   1       (WideMemo)                                          NO  NO      0       NO  YES NONE    NO  NO
```

I expected this view to show me all invisible columns it did not.

```
select * from dba_unused_col_tabs;
```

No Records found

How do I query all the invisible columns in the database?

Comment: Unused and invisible are two different terms. Column is unused if you `ALTER TABLE T SET UNUSED(c)`. It disables the column from being used without freeing any data from disk, thus preserving the same performance of the database. You delete the column later in a more idle time of a day. Invisible column is not shown to applications, yet it still exists and works the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, hidden_column 
  FROM user_tab_cols 
 WHERE hidden_column='YES';
```

Or, as you asked for all columns in the database:

```
SELECT owner, table_name, column_name, hidden_column 
  FROM all_tab_cols 
 WHERE hidden_column='YES';
```

EDIT:

ALL_TAB_COLS is nicely explained in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170359/what-are-oracle-hidden-fields)